# Where to start developing a 2D puzzle game

Tags: unity, 2d, javascript, html5, construct-2

I would like to start developing a 2D puzzle games, much like sudoku for example. I would like to publish it on Facebook and on gaming websites, like miniclip, agame, kongregate. The game should have a premium part for which people can pay. In a second stage I would like to make the game available for mobile devices, Android and Apple and also offer a premium paid section. I would like to accomplish this with one code base.

First of all is this possible? Secondly at which platforms should I look: Unity, HTML5 frameworks, Construct2, ...

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you to start working on your first game to get enough skills and global knowledge on video game development before wondering about platforms or selling plans.

Read about video game development (through books, internet...). Learn how to make a game. Fail at making a dozen of games. And only then you'll probably be confident and skilled enough to start thinking about where to release your game and how to sell it.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to have a common code base if you use cross-platform technologies such as Unity or HTML5 frameworks. Though you'll always need some platform-specific work (Facebook app creation, distribution on the app stores, integration with the payment services,...)

Choosing the framework highly depends on your skills and preferences. 
If you like GUI-oriented tools, Unity might be the right choice for you, especially because it's quite popular and active right now.
If you are more code-oriented, you might prefer some lower lever HTML5 frameworks (check http://html5gameengine.com/)